Google OpenID Connect got "internal_failure" response sometimes
I am using a 3-party library oauth2-google to authenticate users with Google accounts. 99.9% of users are fine. However I got 'internal_failure' twice.
The error response is: [error] => internal_failure [error_description] => Internal Error.
The error details:
League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException: internal_failure in /var/www/test/lib/vendor/league/oauth2-google/src/Provider/Google.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/lib/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(628): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google->checkResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #1 /var/www/test/lib/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(784): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #2 /var/www/test/lib/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(767): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->fetchResourceOwnerDetails(Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken)) #3 /var/www/test/lib/client_auth.php(90): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getResourceOwner(Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken)) #4 /var/www/test/web/signin.php(32): Client_Auth::socialLogin('ya29.a31...', 1) #5 {main}

I checked the RFC6749 and OpenID Connect Core 1.0. There is no "internal_failure" error code. Does anyone know why this error code happen? Thank you in advance!
